# Suitable name for a list of prime that works

Tags: prime-numbers, terminology

In my thesis I have a list of prime numbers that works in terms of the research I am doing. I am planning to write a separate lemma regarding these list of primes rather than listing down these primes in every theorem I have. I was told to come up with a suitable name to indicate these primes. So far I have come up with the name "Indicator prime" and "Success primes", unfortunately rejected by the reader. Is there any suggestion for a nicer name to call all the primes that worked in my research. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't really a mathematical question...maybe ask your reader why he/she rejected your proposed names to see if that gives you an idea for something better.

Comment: @aduh The reader said he want something that sounds more mathematical.

Comment: Find a nomen, define it upfront, and use it consistently afterwards. I don't see why the nomen itself would matter, or why your advisor would reject `Indicator` or `Success`. Maybe try `Lemma #7 Primes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write: "The set $B:=\{3,101,149,283,1301\}$ of primes will play a special rôle in this work. The elements of $B$  will be referred to as *basic primes*."

You then can say things like "if $p\in B$ then$\ldots$", or "if $p$ is a basic prime, then$\ldots$".

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. this is what I've been looking for.